# Laravel: Vite auto-reload 10x slower than regular browser page refresh

Tags: laravel, vite

I use Laravel with Vite plugin.

When I make a change in my blade file, Vite causes an automatic page reload but it is very slow - takes about 3 sec (as shown in Laravel debug bar).
When I just make normal browser refresh with F5 button, reload time is noticably faster and the debug bar shows only like 300ms.

What could be the cause of this situation?

**Edit:**
It has clearly something to do with blade components. When I include like 100x `<x-my-crappy-few-lines-component/>` inside blade file, the loading time increases like crazy. Is it possible that Vite reload triggers some kind of unnecesary re-compilation of laravel views?

My current diagnosis is that Laravel's view compilation process is just slow AF and I can do nothing about that.